# Whitelist IFrames from e.g. YouTube with AntiXSS

Tags: antixsslibrary

Is it possible to whitelist e.g. IFrames with the source set to YouTube, when retrieving the content with GetSafeHtmlFragment from microsofts AntiXss library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the HtmlSanitizer safe list is not customisable.

Comment: It is a shame you can't change it.